# PHPUnit: Class name conflict in custom bootstrapper

Tags: phpunit

I wrote a bootstrapper around `PHPUnit_TextUI_Command` so that I can run run a series of separate test suites when I don't pass any arguments to `phpunit`. The gist of the bootstrapper is this block:

```
// this->_default_tests is an array of argument sets.

$runner = new \PHPUnit_TextUI_Command;
if (count($_SERVER['argv']) == 0) {
    foreach ($this->_default_tests as $test_arguments) {
        $result = $runner->run($test_arguments, false);
        if ($result == \PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::FAILURE_EXIT) {
            exit;
        }
    }
} else {
    $runner->run($_SERVER['argv'], false);
}
```

However, I'm having a major problem when I run the default test: `phpunit` crashes with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class MyOrganization\MyPackage\Tests\Unit\Filters\FilterTest, because the name is already in use in /me/MyOrganization/MyPackage/core/tests/Unit/Filters/FilterTest.php on line 24

I double-checked FilterTest.php and confirmed that the namespace declaration matches the expected namespace. Actually, this test runs without issue when I specify arguments to my runner, thus bypassing the default behavior I'm trying to implement.

PHPUnit defines a class of its own named `FilterTest`. There shouldn't be any conflict between PHPUnits classes and my own, and in fact there apparently isn't when I specify arguments to `phpunit`.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Acceptable alternate answer: Is there a way to configure a test suite so that it stops running after the first file or directory of tests that reports an error or failure? (This is what I'm trying to accomplish with the bootstrapper.)

Answer (score 0):

You should write bootstrap file where you require your file before require autoload.php. And in phpunit.xml settings you should add attribute bootstrap with your bootstrap file.

PHPUnitBootstrap.php

```
require "FilterTest.php"; 
include_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

and phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="PHPUnitBootstrap.php"><testsuites>.....
```